# How to resize a cloth while animating

Tags: animation

I am facing an issue while trying to animate my parachute. To create a deploying effect I want to keep its size small at start and then make it larger after a while. But for some reason resizing does not work. If anyone has any ideas for deploying a parachute or solution to this issue it will be appreciated. I am a beginner so kindly guide me accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how you want to resize it, but the cloth simulation uses the geometry it gets with the start of the simulation, from this moment on all positions of all vertices on a certain frame are calculated cumulatively based on this mesh and the previous simulation steps. Every change you make to the mesh in _Object Mode_ or _Edit Mode_ after the simulation starts is not taken into account. And in reality the parachute does not change its size either, it just unfolds.